# “ssl_error_bad_cert_domain” - but only occasionally?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, ssl, apache2, lets-encrypt

I've got a few domains setup on an Ubuntu server (14.04); they each are encrypted with LetsEncrypt (cron jobs setup to auto-renew them as well).

Every once in a while, I will go to `https://domainA.com` and see the the message:

```
ssl_error_bad_cert_domain
```

When I click to view advanced details... it says that the certificate is only valid for `https://domainB.com` which exists on my server also. If I wait about 20 seconds or so and do a hard refresh (ctrl+shift+r in firefox), `domainA` works as normal and the cert error is gone.

Any idea why this occurs from time to time?

Comment: Give the true domain names, not `domainA` and `domainB` and people might be able to help you.

Comment: DomainA, DomainB, mysite.com, anysite.com - does the domain name make a difference if the content of the question is still relevant?

Comment: see for yourself the number of replies you got...

Comment: I posted this months ago - I don't think the lack of providing a real domain name as opposed to a placeholder is the key reason why I didn't get a lot of replies.

A real domain vs. a placeholder domain name for an example does not make a dramatic or worthwhile difference in this case.

If I said "oh, it's www.hjacks.com for domainA and www.toysrus.com for domainB" am I suddenly going to get an answer almost 3 months later? Doubtful.

Comment: If you asked for my VirtualHost info, okay - that could be relevant. Perhaps some cert information, also relevant. But the name of the domain? It could be anything....

Comment: My ideas on your problem could be anything too, but I'm not here to play hide and seek… Good luck to you then to get answers. EOT.